# Jupyter - how to run and install?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I need to install jupyter notebook on two computers (both Linux Mint 19.2 Tina).

On one computer I have installed it and run

```
jupyter notebook
```

I can't run the cell. I click to run and nothing happens. What does not connected mean?

[image]

On the second computer I run

```
jupyter notebook
```

and there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linux/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 15, in <module>
    from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .traitlets import *
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 49, in <module>
    import enum
ImportError: No module named enum
```

I tried to install it

```
pip install --user pip enum34
pip install --upgrade pip enum34
```

but it didn't help. Is it only for python3?

**EDIT**
[image]

Another problem: there is no python2 python3 in the notebook options.

Terminal:

```
jupyter notebook
[I 13:08:08.694 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /media/linux/DATADISK/venv
[I 13:08:08.694 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 13:08:08.694 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7344956fea0cbfc5eaab06066d8503fa35ba999123e5908c
[I 13:08:08.694 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7344956fea0cbfc5eaab06066d8503fa35ba999123e5908c
[I 13:08:08.694 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 13:08:08.697 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/linux/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-12847-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=7344956fea0cbfc5eaab06066d8503fa35ba999123e5908c
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7344956fea0cbfc5eaab06066d8503fa35ba999123e5908c
```

ERROR:

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 20, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application, create_eventloop, create_prompt_layout, create_output
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application'
```

Comment: Hey Alex! Just for clarification, are you using virtual environments? How did you install Jupyter?

Answer (score 1):

Try a fresh start with [Jupiter in a new environment](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-jupyter-notebooks-virtualenv/).

Note: If you are using python 2.7 you need to make sure venv is installed. A

Comment: I have installed venv. But again the run do nothing.  There is an error: A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

Comment: But I am connected.

Comment: Hey there! Sorry to hear it is still not working. Just to make sure, you are running 'Jupiter notebook' on a stand alone terminal? If so, are you keeping it open while trying to use jupyter? And if so, what messages are you getting in the console?

Comment: It works on one of the computers. For the other O add an edit to my question. There are not python2 and python 3 in notebook options. How to get it there?

Comment: Hey there! You might need to install the kernels. Try running 'python3 -m pip install ipykernel' and then 'python3 -m ipykernel install --user' with no quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks and what does error cannot import name 'create_prompt_application' mean? I got it after the second command (more information in the end of my question).

Comment: Hey there! That usually means that the interpreter was not able to import something, usually because it couldn't find it. In this case, we try 'from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application', but can't find it. That is weird because it should have been installed running 'python3 -m pip install ipykernel'. How did that go? Did you get any error messages when you installed the kernel?

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel) (4.2.1)` This commad was fine. However, after opening notebook the problem stayed the same.